# Is <match v-for='match in matches' v-bind:match='match'></match> incorrect? Can I use the match from v-for inside the v-bind on same element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to render some HTML for each match in matches, however, I'm not quite sure if `<match v-for='match in matches' v-bind:match='match'></match>` is actually correct.

More specifically, I am not sure if I can use the `v-bind:match='match'` on the same element as the loop `v-for='match in matches'`. Does the information contained in `match` actually get sent as a prop to the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does.
This is a working Example:

```js
Vue.component('match', 
{
props :['match'],
template : `<div><span>{{match.matchName}}</span></div>`

})
var mapp = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    matches: [
      { matchName: "First Match"},
      { matchName: "Second Match"},
      { matchName: "Yet another Match"}
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<match v-for='match in matches' v-bind:match='match'></match>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is correct Vue syntax and will work. `match` is available as property inside the component `match`.

You might want to rename your variables, however. This is a single line of code and it already starts being confusing ;-).

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on how I should change the variables? My component is called match because it literally renders a match and I've named the variable I'm sending to the match component match because it contains a match information.